# Which exceptions will be raised for the FCVT.WU.D floating point instruction

Tags: compilation, microcontroller, ieee-754, microprocessors, riscv

What would happen if the instruction `fcvt.wu.d` receives a negative double-precision floating point value as its input? What would the output of the operation be and/or which exception would it raise (is it invalid)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing to note: *no floating point instruction throws an exception in RISC-V.*  Floating point exceptions are "accrued" into a Floating Point Control & Status Register (fcsr).  It is the job of the software to check the fcsr and jump to the appropriate exception handling routine.

From the manual, paraphrased:

> The instruction `fcvt.wu.d` takes a 64b floating point double (located in the floating point register file at register `rs1`) and converts it to an unsigned 32b integer word (placed in the integer register file at `rd`).
>
> Numbers will be rounded as specified by the `rm` field of the instruction.

I wrote some code and ran it through the ISA simulator "spike" to check the behavior myself.  I'm loading "-64" into a dp register and then trying to load it back into the integer register file.

```
 register long test, fcsr;
 asm volatile(" li %0, 64\n\tsub %0, x0, %0\n\tfcvt.d.w f1, %0\n\tfcvt.wu.d %0,f1" : "=r"(test));
 asm volatile(" frcsr %0" : "=r"(fcsr));
 printf("result: %d %lu %lx %x\n", test, test, fcsr);
```

This returns:

> result: -1 18446744073709551615 ffffffffffffffff 10.

The NV exception bit is set! If we change the last instruction to a `fcvt.w.d` we get the expected result:

> tmp: -64 18446744073709551552 ffffffffffffffc0 0

**Summary**: the NV exception bit will be set in the fscr, but that must be manually checked by software to be properly handled.